# system first boot service reboot system

Tags: systemd

I am using Debian preseed to build a "base" linux OS in which I have created a 'firstboot.service', to run on first-boot, to set device specific settings - ie host name.  I am distributing the base image via clonezilla to individual kiosks, not running preseed on each device.

To force the first boot ConditionFirstBoot=true I remove the file /etc/machine-id in the last step before I create my clonezille image.

How can I reboot the kiosk automatically from my firstboot script once the customisations is complete?  I need to do this a lightdm does not automatically login until a reboot after my customisations - ie hostname.

I have tried to force a reboot but it does not work and I get an error.

How do I perform a reboot from a first boot script?

Firstboot.service contents /lib/systemd/system/firstboot.service

```
[Unit]
Description=FirstBootSetup
ConditionFirstBoot=true

[Service]
Type=idle
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/bin/bash /root/firstboot.bash

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Script run by firstboot.service /root/firstboot.bash

```
systemd-machine-id-setup
hostname "RANDOM"

if [ -f /etc/machine-id ]; then
  systemctl --force --force reboot
endif
```

systemctl status firstboot

```
systemctl status firstboot
firstboot.service - FirstBootSetup
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/firstboot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-02-07 11:41:45 AEST; 1h 00min ago
Process: 562 ExecStart=/bin/bash /root/firstboot.bash (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 562 (code=exited, status=2)
```

Comment: Could you use just: shutdown -r now?

Comment: The end of your if statement in the bash script looks wrong. It should end with `fi` not `endif`.

Answer (score 3):

It turned out that the shell script was syntactically incorrect and the shell was simply not running the commands.  As mentioned in a question comment, it should have `fi` where it actually had `endif`.